# Attempting to create an array in Swift with UIImageView as the elements

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimageview

I am creating an app where for each 1 second time interval, an image moves around the board. I have done this by creating a timer, putting up 9 images as hidden, and then for each second making the .isHidden for one of the 9 images, false. However, to do this, I created an array with all 9 imageView elements and expected that when I called a randomElement() from my array, one of the ImageViews would be selected. So far, my app has crashed as my array will not except the imageViews. Below I pasted the applicable code but note that the bottom two lines are in a timer function and the array is outside of ViewDidLoad.

```
let kennyArray = [kenny1.self, kenny2.self, kenny3.self, kenny4.self, kenny5.self, kenny6.self, kenny7.self, kenny8.self, kenny9.self ]
randomKenny = kennyArray.randomElement()
randomKenny.isHidden = false
```

Comment: "my app has crashed": Any error message when this happens? Also, why `kenny1.self`: why the `.self`? What is `kenny1` exactly?

Comment: Is kenny1 an instance, did you mean to write self.kenny1?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need `.self`. I think your approach can be improved. Instead of creating an array of `UIImageView` what you need is an array of `UIImage` and one `UIImageView`. After the time interval instead of hiding set the random image from the array to the image view.

```
var images = [image1, image2, image3]

@objc func alterImage() {
    imageView.image = images.randomElement()
    perform(alterImage, with: self, afterDelay: 10)
}
```